# MySQL common followers between accounts

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table set up like this:

```
+------------+-------------+
| Account Id | Follower Id |
+------------+-------------+
|          1 |         900 |
|          1 |         901 |
|          1 |         902 |
|          2 |         900 |
|          2 |         903 |
|          2 |         904 |
|          3 |         901 |
|          3 |         902 |
+------------+-------------+
```

I am trying to work out the commonalities in followers between the Account IDs. The ideal output would be a table of account IDs (rows) vs account IDs (columns) with the number of in common followers. One solution would be to do a

`LEFT JOIN of`Account ID 1`followers with`Account ID 2`followers.`

However, if I have multiple (>10) different account IDs this becomes cumbersome. Is there a way to generate this for any size of account ids?

Comment: Provide us your sample output.

Comment: Yes, use proper tools, like `Neo4j`.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide the desired result, formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with following query followers is above table(account_id,follower_id)

```
SELECT F.account_id as account1,
       C.account_id as account2,
       count(*) common_follower_count 
FROM followers F 
LEFT JOIN followers C ON (F.follower_id=C.follower_id and 
     F.account_id!=C.account_id) 
WHERE C.account_id is not null 
GROUP BY F.account_id,C.account_id;
```